# How do you support com.intellij.psi for a plugin targeting pycharm?

Tags: intellij-plugin

In my plugin, I'm using `com.intellij.psi.PsiMethod` and `com.intellij.psi.PsiClass`. When I target Pycharm with my alternativeIdePath and try to use my plugin, I get a `NoClassDefFound` error for both classes mentioned above. There are 2 parts to my question:

1. Should I be using python specific psi classes (`PyFunction`/`PyClass`) or are the base `com.intellij.psi` classes compatible with pycharm already?
2. If I do need to include a different psi module/library, what would that look like in my build.gradle file?

My intellij section in build.gradle looks like this:

```
intellij {
  version '182.4505.22'
  alternativeIdePath "redacted\\Toolbox\\apps\\PyCharm-P\\ch-0\\182.4505.26"
}
```

My project sdk is JDK1.8, and in my module dependencies I have `Gradle: com.jetbrains:ideaIC:182.4505.22`, `tools.jar`, `pycharm.jar`, and Module Sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `com.intellij.psi.PsiClass` and `PsiMethod` are not "base PSI classes", they are Java PSI classes, and they aren't available in products that do not support Java. In PyCharm, you need to use `PyFunction`/`PyClass`.

To build a plugin that supports both IntelliJ and PyCharm, you need to add the Python plugin as a dependency for your plugin in build.gradle (it provides the same API as PyCharm). In your plugin.xml you need to use optional dependencies on `com.intellij.modules.java` and `com.intellij.modules.python`, so that your Java-dependent components are only loaded in a Java IDE, and your Python-dependent components are only loaded in PyCharm.

Comment: How can I build a plugin having dependencies of com.intellij.modules.java & com.intellij.modules.python?
When I set the pltaformType as IC it cannot find the python module. If I set the platform Type as PC it doesnt find the java module during build. I have also tried with platformType as IU.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to yole's answer, references to intellij's plugin sdk documentation:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/plugin-compatibility.html#exploring-module-and-plugin-apis

The important parts:

Notes about Module and Plugin Dependency:

(1) This table is not exhaustive; other modules are currently available in JetBrains' IntelliJ Platform-based IDEs. To see a list of modules, invoke the code completion feature for the  element contents while editing the plugin.xml file.

(2) The Java language functionality was extracted as a plugin in version 2019.2 of the IntelliJ Platform. This refactoring separated the Java implementation from the other, non-language portions of the platform. Consequently, dependencies on Java functionality are expressed differently in plugin.xml depending on the version of the IntelliJ Platform being targeted:

Syntax for 2019.2 and later releases:
plugin.xml allowable alternative add com.intellij.java

build.gradle required define dependency on Java plugin intellij { plugins = ['com.intellij.java'] }

Syntax required for releases prior to 2019.2, allowable in all releases:
plugin.xml add com.intellij.modules.java